# Making images respond to browser resize with both width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, responsive-design

I have been trying to make images resize proportionally, leaving whitespace, so they are always fully seen in the browser window without having to scroll.  All of the solutions I have found so far can resize the image based on the browser window width, but if the proportions of the browser window don't match the image, then it will cut off the image and the user will have to scroll down to see the rest.  I know that there is also background-size: cover; but I don't want the image to be clipped.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can try vh and vw units in CSS. And accaptable by almost all browsers.

```
img{width:vw;height:vh;}
```

The drawback is image may shrink... So you can try with overflow hidden.

```
img{width:vh;height:vh;overflow:hidden;position:center;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the [`object-fit: contain` property](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/) if you're using `<img>`, or `background-fit: contain` if it's a CSS `background-image`.

http://codepen.io/robinrendle/pen/BywNVX

`object-fit` [doesn't have perfect browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit), but there is [a polyfill for it](https://github.com/anselmh/object-fit).